# page redirecting when we use path variable in spring mvc

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

When i make a request as 'all_profiles' it works fine (i.e jsp file opened)

```
 @RequestMapping("/all_profiles")
public ModelAndView allProfiles() {
 return new ModelAndView("all_profiles","data",manager.getAllProfiles());
}
```

In that page (all_profiles.jsp) when i click on any hyperlinks it gives corresponding jsp pages

```
 /new_profile_create
 /dashboard
```

Because i configured in xml file like this

```
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

when i make a request for "/single_Profile/25 then also it gives result

```
@RequestMapping("/single_profile/{ast}")
public ModelAndView singleProfile(@PathVariable("ast") Integer id) {
   return new ModelAndView("single_profile","profile",manager.getProfile(id));
}
```

But when i click on any hyperlink in this (single_profile.jsp) page it appends at end like this

```
 /single_profile/new_profile_create
 /single_profile/all_profiles
```

Finally i got error : 404 request resource not found

Comment: Check base href tag on your single_profile.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your anchor tag's href attribute with this

```
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/new_profile_create
      and 
${pageContext.request.contextPath}/profiles
```